# Subclassing NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary, subclassing

I am trying to implement a subclass of NSMutableDictionary that returns nil instead of throwing a NSUndefinedKeyException when the key is not present in the Dictionary.

However when I try to add objects to my dictionary I get

```
[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]: method only defined for abstract class
```

NilDictionary.h

```
@interface NilDictionary : NSMutableDictionary {
} 
@end
```

NilDctionary.m

```
@implementation NilDictionary
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
  return nil;
}
@end
```

Do I really have to implement all the methods from NSMutableDictionary again in my subclass or is there some other class I should be subclassing?

**Clarification**: My original problem came down to me not being able to read the documentation properly.

If you need to subclass NSMutableDictionary check out the correct answer. If you want a dictionary that returns nil when your key is not present, NSMutableDictionary does that already.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with a dictionary to cause it to throw an `NSUndefinedKeyException`? Trying to access an invalid key in a dictionary automatically returns `nil` anyways; how are you getting this error?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

In a subclass, you must override both of its primitive methods:

**1. setObject:forKey:**
**2. removeObjectForKey:**

You must also override the primitive methods of the `NSDictionary` class.

---

[NSDictionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary) says:

If you do need to subclass `NSDictionary`, you need to take into account that is represented by a `Class cluster`—there are therefore several primitive methods upon which the methods are conceptually based:

**1. count**
**2. objectForKey:**
**3. keyEnumerator**
**4. initWithObjects:forKeys:count:**

In a subclass, you *must override* all these methods.

`NSDictionary’s` other methods operate by invoking one or more of these primitives. The non-primitive methods provide convenient ways of accessing multiple entries at once.

---

It seems that you need to **override all these six methods** to make your `NSMutableDictionary` subclass work perfect.

Comment: You must also override `initWithObjects:forKeys:count:`

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem. `NSDictionary` (and its mutable counterpart) is part of a class cluster (read more about them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6), under the 'Class Cluster' heading), and should not be subclassed because it causes problems such as what you've mentioned (read the subclassing notes in the [NSDictionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). Whatever it is you need to do, you're going to have a way to extend the classes you want to use in order to do what you want to do. For instance, the above code can easily be placed in a category (read more about categories [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It seems that to subclass a Class Cluster I just need to implement all primitive methods. For NSMutableDictionary this means that I also need to write a simple implementation for
* count
* objectForKey:
* keyEnumerator
* setObject: forKey:
* removeObjectForKey:
I'm hesitant to use a category because as I understand it that would affect every use of NSMutableDictionary within my application?

Comment: Also, I don't know what you're doing wrong, but when you try to access a key not found in a dictionary, it returns `nil` anyway; it doesn't throw an `NSUndefinedKeyException`... What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have just tried it instead of looking for it in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are not getting the exception when passing in "nil" for a KEY (not a value)?